# A question about Jacobson ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Jacobson ring and let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $A[X_1,...,X_n]$. Show that $M\cap A$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

We assume $A$ is commutative. Can someone give some tips for me? I can't solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This question would likely be a better fit at math stack exchange

Comment: Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra* V, §3, no. 4, Theorem 3. Indeed the question is not appropriate for this site.